# Ускорение запроса в google таблицы

Tags: google-apps-script

Помогите сократить время выполнения. Мой скрипт получает данные из формы на сайте методом POST и открывает копию гугл-таблицы аж за 11 сек

```
var userData = e.parameter.userData;
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('--------qv1r90nHZiTwe--------');
// Создаем копию нового документа из шаблона и получаем его URL
var newDocUrl = DriveApp.getFileById('------------51LZnD0zqd----------').makeCopy('Документ', folder).getUrl();
// заходим в новый документ и вставляем полученные из запроса данные
var newDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newDocUrl);
var sheet = newDoc.getSheetByName("Лист1");
sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(userData);
// возвращаем на сайт ссылку на новый документ для открытия в браузере
return ContentService.createTextOutput(newDocUrl);
```

Ниже фрагмент POST запроса на сайте, отправляющего данные для нового документа и отрывающего этот документ при получении ссылки в ответе на запрос

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", myApp, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    window.open(xhr.response);
  }
};
```

Comment: В Apps Script вы никак не оптимизируете этот процесс. Как вариант, попробуйте создавать несколько копий документа заранее. Но вот эти ваши "аж", конечно, показывают насколько плохо вы еще знакомы с технологией.

Comment: @oshliaer - извините за поздний ответ! Воспользовался вашим советом - "Как вариант, попробуйте создавать несколько копий документа заранее." В моем случае единственный рабочий вариант. Благодарю!